# SpringData MongoDB Using projection

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is their any way via which I can use mongodb projection feature to fetch selected fields from the document.

Even after searching for whole day on internet not able to find any clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the [relevant section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e4904) of the docs concerning repositories. Also the [section on querying documents](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-query) has a brief mention of it.

When using `MongoOperations` you can use the `Query` instance to restrict the result to certain fields:

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("lastname").eq("…"));
// Configure the field spec you want to use for this query
query.fields().include(…).slice(…);
```

I've filed [DATAMONGO-839](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-839) to improve the discoverability of this and also polish the JavaDoc of the `Query` class.

Comment: Thaks oliver for your comments. As per spring data documentation, projection is not supported but it is present in the new release candidate of Spring data.

Comment: Both these links are 404.