# Spring ReactiveMongoTemplate querying objects with embedded objects

Tags: java, spring, mongodb-query, reactive-programming

My model is an object with a collection of objects of a different type,

```
class A {
String id;
String field1;
Set<B> beesInA;
}

class B {
String id;
String name;
}
```

I want to find an instance of B whose id is idB which belongs to an instance of A whose id is idA i.e.

SELECT B WHERE A.id = idA and A.beesInA.id = idB

Only class A is a `document` with a corresponding repository `RepoA` that `extends ReactiveMongoRepository<A, String>`

How do I write a query using `ReactiveMongoTemplate` for `RepoA` that will return `Mono<B>` according to the aforementioned criteria?

Similarly how do I update an instance of B that is found using the above criteria?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21475240/11198814) from [Oliver Drotbohm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18122/oliver-drotbohm) I was able to get the result I needed

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is("idA").and("beesInA.id").is("idB"));
query.fields().include("beesInA.$");

template.findOne(query, A.class).flatMapIterable(A::getBeesInA).single();
```

The update of a particular instance of B is very similar

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is("idA").and("beesInA.id").is("idB"));
Update update = new Update().set("beesInA.$", updatedBObject);

template.findAndModify(query,
                    update,
                    new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true),
                    A.class)
                    .flatMapIterable(A::getBeesInA)
                    .filter(b -> b.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("idB")
                    .single();
```

This [post](https://dev.to/andreevich/how-to-build-custom-queries-with-spring-data-reactive-mongodb-1802) has complete info on using `ReactiveMongoTemplate` with `ReactiveMongoRepository`